Column aliasing not working when joining from a view
i am using mariadb version 10.3. When using this query:
SELECT v.id
       ol.name AS a,
       vlf.name AS b
FROM vacancy AS v
LEFT OUTER JOIN organisation AS o ON v.organisation_id = o.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN organisation_localisation_fallback AS ol ON o.id = ol.organisation_id and ol.language_id = 14 and ol.country_id = 19
LEFT OUTER JOIN vacancy_localisation_fallback AS vlf ON v.id = vlf.vacancy_id AND vlf.language_id = 14 AND vlf.country_id = 19
GROUP BY v.id;

It is giving me the result of 2 columns, both named "name", which is of course giving me errors in my code because of the duplicate column names.
I've tried using single or double quotes after the column aliasing, but both don't have a different result.

Both the _fallback tables are views, and this seems to be the root issue of my problem.
By adding the ol.name column in the group by as such: GROUP BY v.id, ol.name does work, but the performance SINKS from 0.06sec to 11sec! So this is disastrous for me.
How can I make the column aliasing work when selecting columns from different views?
Edited:
These are the view definitions for vacancy_localisation_fallback and organisation_localisation_fallback
ALTER algorithm = undefined definer=`root`@`localhost` sql security definer VIEW `vacancy_localisation_fallback` AS SELECT `v`.`id`              AS `vacancy_id`,
       `clang`.`language_id` AS `language_id`,
       `clang`.`country_id`  AS `country_id`,
       (
                SELECT   `vl`.`NAME`
                FROM     `vacancy_localisation` `vl`
                WHERE    `vl`.`vacancy_id` = `v`.`id`
                ORDER BY
                         CASE
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `vl`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `vl`.`country_id` = `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 1
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `vl`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `vl`.`country_id` <> `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 2
                                  WHEN `vl`.`language_id` = 15 THEN 3
                                  ELSE 4
                         END limit 1) AS `NAME`,
       (
                SELECT   `vl`.`description`
                FROM     `vacancy_localisation` `vl`
                WHERE    `vl`.`vacancy_id` = `v`.`id`
                ORDER BY
                         CASE
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `vl`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `vl`.`country_id` = `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 1
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `vl`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `vl`.`country_id` <> `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 2
                                  WHEN `vl`.`language_id` = 15 THEN 3
                                  ELSE 4
                         END limit 1) AS `description`,
       (
                SELECT   `vl`.`offer`
                FROM     `vacancy_localisation` `vl`
                WHERE    `vl`.`vacancy_id` = `v`.`id`
                ORDER BY
                         CASE
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `vl`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `vl`.`country_id` = `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 1
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `vl`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `vl`.`country_id` <> `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 2
                                  WHEN `vl`.`language_id` = 15 THEN 3
                                  ELSE 4
                         END limit 1) AS `offer`
FROM   (`vacancy` `v`
JOIN   `country_language` `clang`) ;


ALTER algorithm = undefined definer=`root`@`localhost` sql security definer VIEW `organisation_localisation_fallback` AS SELECT `o`.`id`              AS `organisation_id`,
       `clang`.`language_id` AS `language_id`,
       `clang`.`country_id`  AS `country_id`,
       (
                SELECT   `ol`.`NAME`
                FROM     `organisation_localisation` `ol`
                WHERE    `ol`.`organisation_id` = `o`.`id`
                ORDER BY
                         CASE
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `ol`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `ol`.`country_id` = `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 1
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `ol`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `ol`.`country_id` <> `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 2
                                  WHEN `ol`.`language_id` = 15 THEN 3
                                  ELSE 4
                         END limit 1) AS `NAME`,
       (
                SELECT   `ol`.`description`
                FROM     `organisation_localisation` `ol`
                WHERE    `ol`.`organisation_id` = `o`.`id`
                ORDER BY
                         CASE
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `ol`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `ol`.`country_id` = `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 1
                                  WHEN (
                                                    `ol`.`language_id` = `clang`.`language_id`
                                           AND      `ol`.`country_id` <> `clang`.`country_id`) THEN 2
                                  WHEN `ol`.`language_id` = 15 THEN 3
                                  ELSE 4
                         END limit 1) AS `description`
FROM   (`organisation` `o`
JOIN   `country_language` `clang`) ;


Please add the error message in full and publish view definitions as text.

Your query is obviously incorrect. It uses incomplete grouping (the output columns are neither a part of grouping expression nor an argument of aggregate function). Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and fix the query incorrectness. It is giving me the result of 2 columns, both named "name" Looks like the shown query and the query which produces the shown output are not the same.

@P.Salmon there is no error message in mysql itself. Because the query just works, however, the columns are both called "name" instead of using the aliasing. When sending this result set to my nodeJS backend, i cannot work with this because of the duplicate column names. I have added the view definitions in the original question. Thanks for your reply.

@Akina I have changed the screenshot to also include the query as per the result set. I have added v.id in the SELECT, i omitted it at first because i wanted to keep the query as simplified as possible. Thank you for your reply.

Please add CREATE TABLE for all tables which are used in the views/query. This allows to reproduce your situation/issue. Maybe add some sample data as INSERT INTO (3-5 rows per table will be enough). Now the assigned aliases ignoring looks like a bug.

mariadb 10.3 reached end of life almost a year ago and no longer receives security updates; consider it insecure and plan on updating to the current stable 11.3 or one of the long term support versions 10.11 or 10.6 as soon as possible.  it may even fix the bug :)
